# Python importing/finding a package with a period in the name

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Using Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm installing someone else's python program, and encountering some trouble in installation and running it.

They have an install shell script; and it currently runs completely through.

When I run the executable python program 'dwgui', i get an error on the line:

```
File "./dwgui", line 6, in <module>
    from dw.gui.dw_gui import MainWindow
ImportError: No module named dw.gui.dw_gui
```

The install shell script is very verbose, and it's output indeed says:

```
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/dw/gui/dw_gui.py -> /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/dw/gui
```

and then:

```
byte-compiling /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/dw/gui/dw_gui.py to dw_gui.pyc
```

so there is a dw/gui/dw_gui.pyc file. (I checked) Is there any way to get that dw.gui.dw_gui package to import and be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/` directory is on your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

Comment: This is actually a bad idea. The package should be properly installed to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/` where Python will find it automatically. A proper `setup.py` file and the normal Python package install mechanisms would do this, no hackery of a shell script should be involved. `PYTHONPATH` is a hack (for one thing, it's not versioned, so a package that isn't source compatible with Python 2 and Python 3 will break the one it doesn't work with), and this program's install script is wrong to not install to user `site-packages` properly.